# Exporting GEE satellite imagery to Numpy array

Tags: google-earth-engine, export, landsat-8, google-earth-engine-python-api

I'm trying to extract LANDSAT-8 images around a lat/lon location, using the Google Earth Engine API for Python.

Specifically, I want to generate a bounding box of 1km by 1km around my point, and extract the pixels for the RGB bands, so my output should be 33 by 33 by 3, given that LANDSAT-8 resolution is 30m.

However, I can't get this to work. I'm generating my box using `ee.Geometry.Point.buffer` and `ee.Geometry.Polygon.bounds`, and then I'm trying to overlay my geometry over LANDSAT-8 images of 2020, of which I want to get the average value pixel-wise (so the annual average image should be 33 by 33 by 3). After that, I plan to extract the data as a `numpy.Array` using the `ee.Image.sampleRectangle` function, but it is not working. Here is a minimal working example:

```
#importing packages
import numpy as np
import ee
ee.Authenticate()
ee.Initialize()

#converting a lon/lat pair to an ee.point object
point=ee.Geometry.Point( [-122.2036486, 37.4237011] )
# converting the point to a patch: we define a circle with a 500m radius, and then we put a box around it
patch=point.buffer(500).bounds() 

#checking that the patch has approximately the right area 1000^2 m^2
patch.area(1).getInfo()

#defining the image: Landsat 8 collection of images from 2020, with RGB bands. We take the mean of them
imagery=ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1").filterDate('2020-01-01', '2020-12-31').select(['B3','B4','B2']).mean()

#getting a matrix from the image for our patch of interest
rect_image = imagery.sampleRectangle(region=patch)

#we should obtain a 33*33 matrix for each one of the 3 bands

#extracting one band to check
band_b4 = rect_image.get('B4')
#checking the shape of the resulting matrix
np.array(band_b4.getInfo()).shape

#the result is 1*1
```

I feel that one problem here is that the `mean()` function is reducing collapsing the dimensions of the images, so my "fix" to that is instead using the `first()` function to get a proper image, even if it is not the average image I want. Here is what happens:

```
imagery2=ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1").filterDate('2020-01-01', '2020-12-31').select(['B3','B4','B2']).first()

#checking the dimensions
imagery2.getInfo()['bands'][1]['dimensions']

#getting a matrix from the image for our patch of interest
rect_image2 = imagery2.sampleRectangle(region=patch)

#in theory, since this is 1000m*1000m and the resolution of the satellite is 30m,
#we should obtain a 33*33 matrix for each one of the 3 bands

#extracting 1 band to check
band_b4_2 = rect_image2.get('B4')

#checking the shape of the resulting matrix
np.array(band_b4_2.getInfo()).shape

#now we get an error
```

How could I solve this?

I have tried a lot of things like using `ee.ImageCollection.filterBound` over the image collection, `ee.Image.clip`, and I have tried to export the images in `TIFF` or `TFRecord` formats with the `ee.batch.Export.image.toDrive` method, but that also hasn't worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a comment was made here I was reminded of this question. After a while I was able to solve my issues, I wrote a little tutorial of how to export imagery in my [github page](https://github.com/nicolas-suarez/landsat_8_tutorial), but the most relevant to me was the following:

- Defining my area to be clipped didn't worked after using `bounds`, so I ended up doing the following to convert the patch around the pixel to an `ee.Geometry.Rectangle` object:

```
    region= point.buffer(len/2).bounds().getInfo()['coordinates']
    #defining the rectangle
    coords=np.array(region)
    #taking min and maxs of coordinates to define the rectangle
    coords=[np.min(coords[:,:,0]), np.min(coords[:,:,1]), np.max(coords[:,:,0]), np.max(coords[:,:,1])]
    rectangle=ee.Geometry.Rectangle(coords)
```

- The rest of the problems were associated to the arguments used when exporting the function. To clip the image, I used `image.filterBounds(rectangle).mean()`, where image is an `ee.ImageCollection` object, and `rectangle` is the previously defined geometry. Using `mean()` converts this to an `ee.Image` object.

  With that done, I added the following arguments to either the `ee.batch.Export.image.toDrive`or `ee.batch.Export.image.toCloudStorage` besides the obvious ones (like the image we are exporting or the destination of the file:

  - `region=str(region)` to pass the previous list of coordinates of the geometry as a string.
  - `dimensions="33x33"` to pass the number of pixels to be included in the image.
- When the image was exported to either of the sources, I used the `imageio` package, and did something like `np.array(imageio.imread(image_path))` to convert the image from `TIFF` to an `np.array`.

Answer (score 0):

You can export the image to your drive (or gdrive):

Consider `l8_image` is an image `ee` object which you want to save.

```py
### Getting the filenames - might be useful
l8_img_meta = l8_img.getInfo()
imagename = l8_img_meta.get('properties',{}).get('PRODUCT_ID') #fetches the name
```

**Storing the image as a .tif**

This is a task command to GEE, you will have to wait a bit for it to finish

```py
task_config = {
    'image': l8_img,
    'fileFormat': 'GeoTIFF',
    'folder': '<foldername>',
    'fileNamePrefix': imagename[0:19],
    'description': "clipped area",
    'scale':20,
    'region':poly_area
}

# This is how we order it to start
task = ee.batch.Export.image.toDrive(**task_config )
task.start()

### check task status - you can see if it failed, it's running or finished
task.status()
```

Operating with rasters in Python:

```py
# required: pyrsgis, rasterio, pyproj

import rasterio
import rasterio.plot
import pyproj
from pyrsgis.convert import changeDimension


### loading the file
s2_data = "path to file"

### loading and checking
ds1, bands = raster.read(s2_data)
print(ds1)
print(bands.shape) 

bandByPixel = changeDimension(bands)/10000. #we have to devide all values by 10k - its a conversion from bits to reflectances
bandByPixel_t = np.transpose(bandByPixel)
print(bandByPixel.shape)
print(bandByPixel_t.shape)

#opening the raster
with rasterio.open(s2_data) as src:
    subset = src.read(7)/10000.

#plotting the raster
plt.figure(figsize=(6,8.5))
plt.imshow(subset)
plt.colorbar(shrink=0.5)
#plt.title(f'Band 4 Subset\n{window}')
plt.xlabel('Column #')
plt.ylabel('Row #')
```

By here, it should be `np.array` or easily convertible.

Comment: Thanks Nuno! My problems were mainly how to take the mean of the `ImageCollection` and how to properly intersect my `Geometry` with my image, but I can use what you mentioned to later export the images properly to my desired format.

Comment: Just checking to confirm that there's not a way to go straight to the `np.array` (eg, avoiding exporting as a .tif then importing back in?) I'm able to get a list, but would be great to just get the np.appy

`img_list =ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1").filterDate('2020-01-01', '2020-12-31').select(['B3','B4','B2']).mean().reduceRegion(reducer=ee.Reducer.toList(),geometry=patch,scale=30)`


`print(img_list.getInfo())`

Comment: I actually figured out how to do this in the end (I'm going to answer the question now), but I'm not aware of a good way to avoid the `.tif` format. In my final approach I used `ee.batch.Export.image.toDrive` (`ee.batch.Export.image.toCloudStorage` works in a very similar way) because it generates only one `TIFF` file with all the channels of the image rather than a `ZIP` file with one file for each channel.

After downloading the file, I used the `imageio` package, and did something like `np.array(imageio.imread(image_path))` to convert the image from `TIFF` to an `np.array`.